# Exibir média salarial por anos de serviço

Tags: sql

Tenho a tabela FUNCIONARIO que tem como colunas matricula, nome, anoServico, salario.

Gostaria de exibir a média salarial por anoServico.

Como fazer?

Obrigada!

Comment: Qual a razão da pergunta ficar pendente ?!

Comment: A pergunta já foi até respondida. Porque agora pendente???

Comment: O SO parece que mede a pergunta pelo tamanho se tiver 500M e receita de miojo passa , se for curto é marcada.... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Santana,

Em SQL existe a função AVG, que retorna a média de valores.

Você pode utilizar a função AVG no campo salario e agrupar pelo anoServico, seria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT AVG(salario) media_salaria, anoServico
  FROM FUNCIONARIO 
 GROUP BY anoServico
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp